# React Native Flatlist - Each child must have "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a couple of simple FlatLists, each showing custom list items for divisions and shops. I get the error that each child should have a unique "key" prop, but I have defined both a `keyExtractor` as well as tried to add a `key` prop to the custom list row component. I.e.

```
<FlatList
  style={_styles.list}
  data={this.props.divisions}
  extraData={this.state.chosenDivisionId}
  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
  renderItem={this._renderDivisionItem}/>}
/>

_keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id

_renderDivisionItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    let typedItem: DivisionData = item;
    return (
      <ShopListItem
        text={typedItem.name}
        selected={this.state.chosenDivisionId === typedItem.id}
        itemId={typedItem.id}
        key={typedItem.id} /* Have tried with and without this */
        onPress={itemId => this._updateStateForDivisionChosen(itemId)}
      />
    );
  };
```

How come I still get the warning, did I do anything wrong? The keyExtractor method works fine on my other FlatLists. And of course, the IDs used are unique

Comment: The setup looks correct, the only thing i can think of that might throw that error is if not every object in that array has an item.id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue.

The app is using redux for state management, and the lists in question are initialized with an initial state. The models has changed the property name for id, from `divisionId` and `shopId` to plain `id` for both lists - but I'd forgotten to change this in the initial state object. Therefore, when the lists rendered before data arrived, the key extractor was not able to find an `id` prop on the item, as they were called `divisionId` or `shopId` instead. When data arrived, the state would be overriden, and keys would populate just fine.

Thanks for the answers, I hope this blunder can help someone in the future :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line with this

```
_keyExtractor = (item, index) => typedItem.id
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't make sense :) The passed object is called `item`, and using typedItem crashes with nullpointer. Its just used in render for intellisense